# pytest passes in pycharm but fails from command line

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I have a number of test classes wtih one specific one containing 12 tests.  Two of these tests pass within pycharm but not in powershell.  One of them is this:

```
    def test_create_block_when_called_returns_correct_no_jbs(self):
        designer = BlockDesigner(CsvStore(self.config), FakeRouter(), self.config)
        block = designer.create_block("BK1")

        result = len(block.junction_boxes)

        assert result == 10
```

It passes perfectly from within pycharm.  When run outside, it fails on the assert criteria:

```
>       assert result == 10
E       assert 9 == 10
```

This would suggest it gets a different setup from the command line than when run inside pycharm.  This test class has a `setup_method` that instantiates the required config files and am specifically careful to get the current paths since these tests also run in DevOps:

```
    def setup_method(self):
        self.path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())
        self.config = Configuration(self.path + "/test_config.yml").get_config()
```

I have a similar problem with one other test in this test class but all other 10 using the same setup, passes on the command line.

First time I have ever encountered this.  Is there something I am missing in the `setup_method` perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried to look at what the difference inside `block.junction_boxes` is? There might be different default encodings being used - it'd be helpful to start looking at _what_ the difference is and then _why_ the difference happens, not just that there's a difference in one environment compared to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it was indeed a config setup issue.  These errors are annoying and was completely mine.  There was an additional config file path that I had to pre-fix with `str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())`.  An oversight.